# How to do a shadeless vertex color material in Blender 3.2.2 with Eevee?

Tags: materials, vertices, color, shadeless

I'm trying to do a shadeless vertex color material in Blender version 3.2.2. using Eevee.

I tried to connect an emission shader but the material renders pink.

There is two screenshots bellow for reference:

[image: Vertex color material setup in Blender 2.2.2]

[image: Emission and principled renders pink]

You can also download the .blend with the setup for vertex colors in Eevee here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rn_IpVwCIsqQG7t3-TQ85ks6PPvBl8It/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Send a screenshot using an emission shader? That should work.

Comment: Additional screenshot added! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your are trying to use Principled BSDF and the emission shader together. Delete the Principled BSDF and replace it with an Emission Node.

If you also want the white to be true white, go to the Color Management Tab (Inside render properties) and select Standard for View Transform.

Here you can download the .blend file with the solution:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1leb8NHDufGeyWuh5nW81RKzS13MQTQ51/view?usp=sharing

[image: Shadeless vertex color material in Blender 3.2.2]

Comment: Thank you so much @Bloop! I made some edits to your post trying to make it even clearer. I hope you like it. All the best for you. :)